# How not to repeat test cases

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testng

Friends,

I use eclipse TestNG and webdriver along with selenium to automate test cases. Also, I would like to mention that I import data from excel into scripts to make the scripts dynamic and executable for different users.

I have many modules in php website (one I'm automating) like Sales module, Workers module. The problem is the TestNG executes each testcase @Test independently i.e. for each test case, it starts execution from login, it is not possible if I execute Sales test case starting from login and then continue with another test case Workers. I don't want to login/logout again and again as it wastes time. I didn't have programming experience before selenium. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Testng allows dependency between tests. Like this:

```
public class App {

    @Test
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("This is method 1");
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = { "method1" })
    public void method2() {
        System.out.println("This is method 2");
    }

}
```

Maybe your test should depend on loging test.

Hope help!

Answer (score 0):

You can put login in `@BeforeClass` or `@BeforeTest` or `@BeforeSuite`, which would mean it would execute once and all `@Tests` would run after that (`@BeforeClass` would do it once at class level).  However, parallel runs would not be possible then and you would have to run sequentially.